# How do you make a bot send a specific username of user

Tags: discord, discord.py

As example, I want the bot to send the users name like: "!hi Jake"     bot: "Jake"

So the bot will only say "Jake" "not the entire command" if someone can help me with this I would highly appreciate that!

Comment: Show your current code and an indication of where the new functionality needs added. This seems too vague otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to simply respond with the text that is passed in with the command, then you can do this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx, user : str):
    await ctx.send(user) # !hi Jake will return Jake
```

However, if you want it to respond using the `Member` object which contains a lot of information about the member object passed in, then you can do this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx, user : discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f"{user.name}") # or user.mention or user.display_name
```

Keep in mind that this second solution will only work if the name passed in is the name of someone in the server that you're calling the command in. I think for what you want, the first solution should work just fine.

Edit: After looking at ur comment, you need to use your `on_message` event to check whether a message starts with `hi`. If it does, then it'll print the name that comes after it. Copy paste this code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if (message.author == client.user):
        return
    if message.content.startswith('hi'):
        words = message.content.split()
    for i in words:
        if i == 'hi':
            name = words.index(i) + 1
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"hi {words[name]}", description=f"{random.randint(1,100)}")
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Hi it worked but I want it to work like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/YM0RFKUi

Comment: So it will say the users name inside the embed title

Comment: @VenusExploits Make that clear in the question, try to include any code you think is relevant and explain clearly what you have tried and what you want to do

Comment: @VenusExploits I've edited my answer to show you how to do the embed. Make sure to click the green check mark button next to my post if this answer helped you out!

Comment: I have fixed that problem but I mean that It will execute that command without the prefix like without "!" just *hi jake* and the bot: *jake*

Comment: @VenusExploits I now understand what you’re asking for. I will answer your question in a few hours.

Comment: @VenusExploits I've edited my answer with new code. Try it out.